# Обработка двух запросов

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно, чтобы выводило по двум запросам.

```
<?php 
    $myid = $userinfo["id"];
  $friends1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE idUser='$myid' AND status='0'") or die("Ошибочный запрос к БД".mysql_error());
  $friends2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE idUserFriend='$myid' AND status='0'") or die("Ошибочный запрос к БД".mysql_error());
   if($friends) { // Если mysql_query вернула не пустой результат
    if(!mysql_num_rows($friends))
    echo "Нету друзей";
    while ($friendwall = mysql_fetch_array($friends1)) { // Получаем строки из результата

      echo $friendwall["id"];

  }
   }
?>
```

Сделал вот такой вывод. 
У меня в таблице friends два столбца - **idUser** и **idUserFriend**, в этих столбцах разные числа, мне надо, чтобы выводило по обоим. 
То есть в idUser у меня 1, а в idUserFriend 2. 
И если в одной из них совпадает с 1, то выводить, и надо это сделать как-то одним запросом, а если в таблице

```
idUser      idUserFriend
   1              2
   2              1
```

то выводим два столбца.

Comment: Стоп-стоп. Какие скобки? Вы в курсе про приоритет логических операций?

Comment: Да, согласен, со скобками все норм)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (idUser='$myid' OR idUserFriend='$myid') AND status='0' ?`

Answer (score 0):

Несколько короче:

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE '$myid' IN (idUser,idUserFriend) AND status='0'
```